# matplotlib imshow: map specific colors to specific values

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

suppose I have a 2D matrix of 1s and 0s and I plot it with `imshow`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow([[1,0],[0,1]])
```

I would get the following output

[image]

Is there an easy way to map the colours to specific values? for example the `0` to grey and the `1` to blue? I presume something like

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
cm = ListedColormap(['grey', 'blue'])
plt.imshow([[1,0],[0,1]], cmap=cm)
```

However that misses the mapping with the values. Couldn't find anything straightforward on SO.

Comment: I run your code and get [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCVnA.png) and it seems fine. What do you mean by _However that misses the mapping with the values_?

Comment: `NameError: name 'ListedColormap' is not defined` always include all relevant imports

Comment: @Zephyr it means that 0 won't be mapped to grey and 1 to blue. For example if I invert the colormap to `'blue', 'grey'` the colours will be inverted, independent of the values.

Comment: added the `ListedColormap` import